# How do replace [] , in bash

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have python returned list as

```
list = ['A','B-D','A12.C']
```

I need to convert this list to a bash array.

I tried via sed `'s/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/ /g'` but it does not found useful. It replaced [] but inserted blank spaced in between.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, in the future it would be helpful to include the undesired output/any error messages you are getting to making debugging easier. Otherwise, your question is well written for a newbie.

Comment: Why the `regex`, `perl`, `awk`, or `sed` tags?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [json](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/json.html#json.dump) library for these response objects, you need to also call the `dumps()` method to convert the json object into a string. Then you can just print it.

Comment: Not without knowing more about the structure of the `api_response` objects.  `json.dumps(api_1_response.json())` might turn them into strings, but I cannot be certain. Read the documentation I linked and teach yourself or share more code and I can try to help.